# Registering touch events of layered uiimageviews with overlapping transparent properties

Tags: iphone, xcode, events, uiimageview, touch

I'm new at this and have looked at several posts already related to this question but none seem to provide the answer I need.

I have multiple layered uiimageviews within one "base" uiimageview.  The uiimageviews display arrays of images with small opaque colored parts and large transparent parts.  How do I get a touch event to ignore the layers of transparent parts to activate the opaque underlayer?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `userInteractionEnabled` property of `UIImageView` is disabled.  If you want only the "lowest" view to receive touch events, you should create a subclass of `UIImageView` in which you explicitly set `userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and implement `touchesBegan`, etc.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful, but I have about 20 views stacked and I need each view active but the base view. Can I transiently disable views whose touched parts are transparent? And then enable them when their opaque parts are touched?

Comment: If you set `userInteractionEnabled` for each view, then they will register touches based on which one is "higher" in the view hierarchy.  Are you trying to create one of those cascading moveable/rotatable/resizable image apps?